# Marshalling arrays of structures in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, marshalling

I have a third-party C DLL that I am trying to call from VB.NET.

The API has in and out structures that are multi-level. For the sake of brevity:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int                 nObjectID;
    char                szObjectType[128];
    int                 nConfidence;
    int                 nAction;
    DH_RECT             BoundingBox;
    DH_POINT            Center;
    int                 nPolygonNum;
    DH_POINT            Contour[DH_MAX_POLYGON_NUM];
    DWORD               rgbaMainColor;
    <snip>
}
```

refers to two other structures (DH_RECT & DH_POINT). These are defined as:

```
typedef struct 
{
    long                    left;
    long                    top;
    long                    right;
    long                    bottom;
} DH_RECT, *LPDH_RECT;
typedef struct 
{
    short                   nx;
    short                   ny;
} DH_POINT, *LPDH_POINT, NET_POINT, *LPNET_POINT;
```

In my VB.NET version, I used this:

```
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)>
    Public Structure DH_RECT
        Public left As Int32
        Public top As Int32
        Public right As Int32
        Public bottom As Int32
    End Structure
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)>
    Public Structure DH_POINT
        Public nx As Int16
        Public ny As Int16
    End Structure
   <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=4)>
    Public Structure DH_MSG_OBJECT
        Public nObjectID As Int32 
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=128)>
        Public szObjectType As String
        Public nConfidence As Int32
        Public nAction As Int32
        Public BoundingBox As DH_RECT 
        Public Center As DH_POINT
        Public nPolygonNum As Int32 
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=16)>
        Public Contour() As DH_POINT
        Public rgbaMainColor As UInt32
    <snip>
```

After calling the DLL function and moving the result into the structure using Marshal.PtrToStructure, everything after nPolygonNum is 0 or garbage. Mostly 0.

I suspect the error to be in the declaration for Contour. This is supposed to be an array of 16 of the type structure DH_POINT. I think the declaration should not be `<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=16)>` but can't get any other type to work.

Comment: I see `int`, `long` and `short` in your C++ definitions which are treated as `Int32` and `Int16`. Is this correct (sorry, I'm quite C++ ignorant). Otherwise the structs look good to me, maybe check the pack size of the DH_POINT, is it really 1 (resp. 2). and not 4? (DH_RECT is fine, that are anyway multiples of 4).

Comment: Agreed with the comment on packing, I think the default for the C compiler is 4 unless otherwise specified e.g. with `#pragma pack`.

Comment: The C header file has a number of definitions at the top, such as ````#ifdef RELEASE_HEADER #define LONG int```` etc. The DH-MSG_OBJECT structure has this: ````ifndef LINUX64_JNA #pragma pack(push) #pragma pack(4) #endif```` All of which leads to believe that they have used different pack sizes for different structs. The header file is 71,000 lines (!) so is easy to mistranslate stuff.

Comment: You might want to try using packing of 4 on the VB side.  That looks like the "normal" build is using 4 on the C side.

Comment: Question: The ifndef pack(4) declaration is given only for the DH_MSG_OBJECT structure. What is the default packing in C? Does it differ for X86 and X64?